# How to connect one HDMI and one VGA monitor to a laptop?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I have a Lenovo P400 with Windows 8 Operating System laptop and the graphics card is an *Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000*. Currently, I have a 20" LCD external monitor connected to the laptop through a VGA cable (since the external monitor only supports VGA, not HDMI). I am about to buy a second external monitor (which supports HDMI). I have two similar questions so I decided to make it in one post.

1. Will my laptop be able to extend it's screen across all three screens (the two external monitors as well as the laptops screen)? (with one of the external monitors connected through HDMI and the other connected through VGA).
2. Will my laptop be able to at least display on both external monitors without displaying on it's own screen?

There is a port which says 'HDMI' on my laptop.
Let me know if more information is required.

Answer (score 1):

It's very unlikely this will work unfortunately. It's a limitation of many graphics cards. Connecting the secondary external output will either not work, disable the primary output or clone both outputs. I'd definitely suggest testing it with another monitor if someone else you know has one available.

Alternatively,  you can purchase external usb video cards that would allow for this. I've achieved this using a Toshiba Dynadock before however I have no doubt there are cheaper options. Good luck!